# Python3 tkinter import error on linux "import tkinter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have looked in to it [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438283/tkinter-error-with-importing) but can't find out.
I am using python3 on linux Ubuntu([PopOs](https://pop.system76.com/))
sudo apt-get install python3-tk  dit not work

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 3, in 
import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter module not found on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Install from python.org [Here](https://python.org)

When installing click custom and tick everything, Including tk and tcl libraries.

Comment: There are no Linux installers on python.org. You either need to get it from your distro or build from source.

Comment: sudo apt install reinstall python3?